# Drag and drop for files upload, Select some files and try to add another some files in another folder previously selected files are lost

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I create a custom drag and drop for files upload, But the issue is I select some files and try to add another some files in another folder but previously selected files are lost. Is there any way to keep both files to upload.

```js
(function($){
    var fileArr = [];
      $("#images").change(function(){
        // check if fileArr length is greater than 0
         if (fileArr.length > 0) fileArr = [];

          $('#image_preview').html("");
          var total_file = document.getElementById("images").files;
          if (total_file.length > 0){$('.photoimg').hide();}
          if (!total_file.length) return;
          for (var i = 0; i < total_file.length; i++) {
            if (total_file[i].size > 1048576) {
              return false;
            } else {
              fileArr.push(total_file[i]);
              $('#image_preview').append("<div class='img-div' id='img-div"+i+"'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"' class=' image' title='"+total_file[i].name+"'><div class='middle'><button id='action-icon' value='img-div"+i+"' class='btn btn-danger' role='"+total_file[i].name+"'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></div></div>");
            }
          }
      });

      $('body').on('click', '#action-icon', function(evt){
          var divName = this.value;
          var fileName = $(this).attr('role');
          $(`#${divName}`).remove();

          for (var i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
            if (fileArr[i].name === fileName) {
              fileArr.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
          if (fileArr.length > 0){$('.photoimg').hide();}else{$('.photoimg').show();}
        document.getElementById('images').files = FileListItem(fileArr);
          evt.preventDefault();
      });

    function FileListItem(file)
    {
        file = [].slice.call(Array.isArray(file) ? file : arguments)
        for (var c, b = c = file.length, d = !0; b-- && d;) d = file[b] instanceof File
        if (!d) throw new TypeError("expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects")
        for (b = (new ClipboardEvent("")).clipboardData || new DataTransfer; c--;) b.items.add(file[c])
        return b.files
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragdrop text-center">
    <div class="upload-text photoimg"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> <span>Drag & Drop files here or click to browse</span> </div>
    <input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="images" multiple>
    <div id="image_preview" style="width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I THINK you're asking about the browser UI and how when you select files and then select files again it doesn't retain previously selected files? Maybe? If so then this is a browser - / operating system - level thing and you have no control over it. You can start uploading as soon as files are selected?

Comment: https://frontendscript.com/demo/jquery-multiple-image-upload-with-preview-and-delete/
Please check this demo, this plugin allows this option. But apple devices aren't supporting this plugin that is the problem.

Comment: Indeed. Like I said. An OS / browser issue.

Comment: array concept is working?